# how to change position of Datatable Export buttons in custom div / outside the table

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I want to display the export buttons in outside the table.

I saw one example in stackoverflow but that's is a Select options method see that example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348631/datatables-export-button-display-in-custom-position)

If anyone knows how to do that mean please modify it and share jsfiddle link.

Here is my code Im using bootstrap4 datatable.

**Javasript**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datatable").DataTable(),
        $("#datatable-buttons")
            .DataTable( { 

                lengthChange: !1, 

                buttons: [
                    
                    {
                        extend:    'copy',
                        text:      '<i class="fas fa-copy"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Copy',
                        className: 'btn btn-md mr-2 btn-copy'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'excel',
                        text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Excel',
                        className: 'btn btn-md mr-2 btn-excel'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'pdf',
                        text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'PDF',
                        className: 'btn btn-md mr-2 btn-pdf'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'print',
                        text:      '<i class="fas fa-print"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Print',
                        className: 'btn btn-md mr-2 btn-print'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'colvis',
                        text:      '<i class="fas fa-eye"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Visibility',
                        className: 'btn btn-md mr-2 btn-colvis'
                    },

                ],

                lengthChange: true,
                searching: true

            })
            .buttons()
            .container()
            .appendTo("#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)");
});
```

**Html Code**

```html
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">

                                <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
                                       style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">
                                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                                        <tr class="text-center">
                                            <th>Id</th>
                                            <th>User Image</th>
                                            <th>Username</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th>Role</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php foreach ($userdetails as $key => $userdetail): ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $userdetail['id']; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $userdetail['user_image']; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $userdetail['username']; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $userdetail['email']; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $userdetail['role']; ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php endforeach ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end col -->
                </div> <!-- end row -->
```

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwxTX.png)

Comment: anyone Answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your given code pretty much works out of the box, outside of the final `appendTo()` line in the Javascript. Changing the target from `#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)` to any valid `appendTo()` target will move the buttons to the appropriate place. See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/appendto/) for jQuery's `appendTo()`. You could also use other DOM manipulation methods, such as `prependTo()`.

Here is a working example where the table buttons are in an outside div.

https://jsfiddle.net/ontj8kLs/8/