# Move Datatable export button to bottom of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

I have created a export option in my datatable I want it to show below the table right now it is showing above the table. Talking about the download button to be shown at end of the table next to paging maybe.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        'responsive': true,
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });

    // Handle click on "Expand All" button
    $('#btn-show-all-children').on('click', function(){
        // Expand row details
        console.log('Inside click');
        table.rows(':not(.parent)').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click');
    });

    // Handle click on "Collapse All" button
    $('#btn-hide-all-children').on('click', function(){
        // Collapse row details
        table.rows('.parent').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click');
    });

    $('#btn-show-all-children').trigger('click');
});
```

This is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x5q3anys/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataTable export button outside table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308273/datatable-export-button-outside-table)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At `dom` settings string , put `B` at the end of the string like this:

```
dom: 'frtipB'
```

From the documentation:

> Each table control element in DataTables has a single letter
>   associated with it, and that letter it used in this dom configuration
>   option to indicate where that element will appear in the document
>   order.

Read more: [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

Comment: @BillP Thanks this works. Could you please tell me how to align the button to center ??

Comment: You can use this css: .dt-buttons { text-align: center; }

Comment: @BillP is it possible to do it on js file instead of css?

Comment: you can try to apply css with jquery: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

Answer (score -1):

This positions  export button below table in center

Add this css to css file :

You can edit this css accordingly

```
.dt-buttons {
    /* margin-bottom: -7px; */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it is strike out when I checked on inspect on google chrome.

Comment: what do u mean strike out ?

Comment: is not applied. Well I figure out a different way using CSS. Could I know that can we change the position of paging ? No matter what I try paging seems to hold the right most position.

Comment: That didnt but found a different solution to it. I used this .dataTables_wrapper .dt-buttons {
  float:none;  
  text-align:left;
}

Comment: yes  you can change css of other elements too ...just inspect and see its class and use it as dt-buttons